# Can bootstrapping be applied to summarized data?

Tags: bootstrap

My rudimentary understanding of bootstrapping leads me to believe that the
technique can only be applied to raw data (e.g. collections of `(xi, yi)`) -- not
summarized data (e.g. collections of `(xi, yi_bar, yi_err)`). But [this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50806432/190597) claims somehow
bootstrapping is used on summarized data in numerous scientific publications.

Can you enlighten me on this issue? Can bootstrapping be applied to summarized
data? How is it done?

Do you simply "repopulate" the data set by simulating `(xi, yi)`s such that the
`yi`s are normally distributed about the mean `yi_bar` with standard deviation
`yi_err`? and then do regular bootstrapping?

If so, are there theorems which relate the result one
obtains this way back to the result one *would have obtained* if bootstrapping were applied
to the original raw data?

It seems plausible that the result would be close, but I would feel better about it if
I knew some measure of how close.

Comment: The bootstrap is a general statistical procedure that can be applied to any data, summarized or not. There's not a "right" and "wrong" dataset to apply bootstrap to, but the result of the bootstrap has a different interpretation depending on what data it's applied to. You have to know what question you're trying to answer first - what variance you're trying to measure - to know what data and what bootstrap are appropriate to answer it.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the comment. Are you saying that one of the fundamental
assumptions of bootstrap is that the population distribution can be replaced by
the sample distribution, and so there is no right or wrong technique because its
legitimacy is wrapped into this fundamental assumption? In other words, if I use
some "repopulated" sample distribution based on `(xi, yi_bar, yi_err)` as the
proxy for the population distribution, then there is no right-or-wrongness
attached to it -- it's just my assumption?